# useEffect doesn't update state unless page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, timer, dayjs

I'm trying to create a timer which updates a countdown using **dayjs** and changes the delivery date after a certain cutoff time (4pm) I've got it working however the useEffect doesn't seem to update the **deliveryDate** unless you refresh the page. Once the timer runs out it should update the delivery date automatically

`

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import Countdown from 'react-countdown'
import dayjs from 'dayjs'

const FulfilmentDelivery = ({ cutoffhour }) => {
  const [cutoffTime, setCutoffTime] = useState(
    dayjs().add(1, 'day').hour(cutoffhour).minute(0).second(0)
  )
  const [deliveryDate, setDeliveryDate] = useState(
    dayjs().add(1, 'day').format('dddd D MMM')
  )

  let now = dayjs()
  let isSaturday = now.day() === 6
  let isSunday = now.day() === 0
  let cutoffFriday = now.day() === 5 && now.hour() >= cutoffhour

  useEffect(() => {
    // if it's after 4pm on a weekday set the cutoff time to the next day at 4pm and the delivery date to the next day
    if (now.hour() >= cutoffhour && !cutoffFriday && !isSaturday && !isSunday) {
      setCutoffTime(dayjs().add(1, 'day').hour(cutoffhour).minute(0).second(0))
      setDeliveryDate(dayjs().add(2, 'day').format('dddd D MMM'))
    }
    // if it's after 4pm on thursday, set delivery date and cutoff time to monday
    if (now.day() === 4 && now.hour() >= cutoffhour) {
      setCutoffTime(dayjs().add(4, 'day').hour(cutoffhour).minute(0).second(0))
      setDeliveryDate(dayjs().add(4, 'day').format('dddd D MMM'))
    }

    // if its before 4pm on a friday set delivery date and cutoff time to monday
    if (now.day() === 5 && now.hour() < cutoffhour) {
      setCutoffTime(dayjs().add(3, 'day').hour(cutoffhour).minute(0).second(0))
      setDeliveryDate(dayjs().add(3, 'day').format('dddd D MMM'))
    }

    // if it's the saturday set delivery date and cutoff time to tuesday
    if (isSaturday) {
      setCutoffTime(dayjs().add(3, 'day').hour(cutoffhour).minute(0).second(0))
      setDeliveryDate(dayjs().add(3, 'day').format('dddd D MMM'))
    }

    // if it's the saturday set delivery date and cutoff time to tuesday
    if (isSunday) {
      setCutoffTime(dayjs().add(2, 'day').hour(cutoffhour).minute(0).second(0))
      setDeliveryDate(dayjs().add(2, 'day').format('dddd D MMM'))
    }

    // if it's after 4pm on a friday set delivery date to tuesdsay
    if (cutoffFriday) {
      setDeliveryDate(dayjs().add(4, 'day').format('dddd D MMM'))
    }
  })

  return (
    <div className="align-items-center  d-flex  h-100">
      <span className="display-5" data-icon="z"></span>
      <div className="ps-2  w-100">
        {/* <span className="fw-bold fs-4">Order within</span> */}
        <Countdown
          date={cutoffTime}
          renderer={({ hours, minutes, seconds, completed }) =>
            (cutoffFriday && (
              <>
                <span className="fw-bold fs-6">Order now</span>{' '}
                <span>for delivery on {deliveryDate}</span>
              </>
            )) ||
            (isSaturday && (
              <>
                <span className="fw-bold fs-6">Order now</span>{' '}
                <span>for delivery on {deliveryDate}</span>
              </>
            )) ||
            (isSunday && (
              <>
                <span className="fw-bold fs-6">Order now</span>{' '}
                <span>for delivery on {deliveryDate}</span>
              </>
            )) || (
              <>
                <span className="fw-bold fs-6">Order within</span>{' '}
                <span className="text-danger fw-bold fs-6">
                  {`undefined` !== typeof window &&
                    `${hours >= 1 ? `${hours} hrs ` : ``}${
                      minutes >= 1 ? `${minutes} mins` : ``
                    }${seconds >= 1 ? ` ${seconds} sec` : ``}`}
                </span>
                <br /> for delivery on {deliveryDate}
              </>
            )
          }
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default FulfilmentDelivery
```

`

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any timers in your code.

Comment: Don't think DayJS will automatically update time and notify you, so you need to check over and over again with a reasonable interval, so you can use `setTimeout()` or something like this to check date has changed  or not and update state accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an interval to periodically refresh the state. I'd say that's your best option because there is nothing else to react against.

It's as simple as making a mount effect with a setInterval call in it.

```
const FulfilmentDelivery = ({ cutoffhour }) => {
  const now = dayjs();

  const [cutoffTime, setCutoffTime] = useState(
    now.add(1, "day").hour(cutoffhour).minute(0).second(0)
  );
  const [deliveryDate, setDeliveryDate] = useState(now.add(1, "day").format("dddd D MMM"));

  const choose = () => {
    const conditions = {
      // In order of precedence
      isSunday: now.day() === 0,
      // etc
    };

    applyDayAddConfig(conditions);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const ref = setInterval(() => choose(), 5000); // Refresh all of the state every 5 seconds
    return () => {
      clearInterval(ref);
    };
    // This is a mount effect because its dependency list is empty
  }, [choose]);

  // Might as well remove all the unnecessary duplication
  const applyDayAddConfig = (conds: object) => {
    const thisCond = Object.entries(conds).find(([_, value]) => value === true);
    const [timeDayAdd, dateDayAdd] = {
      isSunday: [2, 2],
      isSaturday: [3, 3],
      // Add config here
    }[thisCond[0]];

    setCutoffTime(now.add(timeDayAdd, "day").hour(cutoffhour).minute(0).second(0));
    if (dateDayAdd !== null) setDeliveryDate(now.add(dateDayAdd, "day").format("dddd D MMM"));
  };

  return;
};
```